# Auto load OnDemand prism modules when others are set to Startup in app.config

Tags: wpf, module, prism, app-config

We are using Prism 7 with unity for a WPF application.  There are a set of prism modules that have dependencies on other modules.  I would like to be able to do all configuration via app.config to avoid having to recompile when turning features on and off.  So, say we have the following three modules:

```
<configSections>
<section name="modules" type="Prism.Modularity.ModulesConfigurationSection, Prism.Wpf" />
</configSections>

<appSettings>
....
</appSettings>

<modules>

<!--SOME KIND OF CONNECTION MODULE-->
<module
  moduleName="IConnectionsModule"
  assemblyFile="Connections.Module.dll"
  moduleType="Connections.Module.ConnectionsModule, Connections.Module"
  startupLoaded="true" 
/>

<!--SOME KIND OF MIDDLE MODULE-->
<module 
  moduleName="IMiddlewareModule"
  assemblyFile="Middleware.Module.dll"
  moduleType="Middleware.Module.MiddlewareModule, Middleware.Module"
  startupLoaded="false"
  >
  <dependencies>
    <dependency moduleName="IConnectionsModule"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>

<!--SOME KIND OF TOP-LEVEL MODULE-->
<module 
  moduleName="IToplevelModule"
  assemblyFile="Toplevel.Module.dll"
  moduleType="Toplevel.Module.ToplevelModule, Toplevel.Module"
  startupLoaded="true"
  >
  <dependencies>
    <dependency moduleName="IMiddlewareModule"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>

</modules>
```

The Connection module will always be loaded.  The Middle is dependent on Connection module and is set has `startupLoaded="false"` so its Initialization Mode will be set to `OnDemand`.  The Top Level module is dependent on Middle module and is set to `startupLoaded="true"` so its Initialization Mode is `WhenAvailable`.  This interpretation can be seen in `ConfigurationModuleCatalog.desktop.cs`:

```
ModuleInfo moduleInfo = new ModuleInfo(element.ModuleName, element.ModuleType)
{
    Ref = GetFileAbsoluteUri(element.AssemblyFile),
    InitializationMode = element.StartupLoaded ? InitializationMode.WhenAvailable : InitializationMode.OnDemand
};
```

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Modularity/ConfigurationModuleCatalog.Desktop.cs#L73

My expectation was that even if the Middle module is not loaded on start, Prism would recognize the need since Toplevel module is and, therefore, automatically start it.  But instead it throws an error:

```
    Module IToplevelModule is marked for automatic initialization when the application starts, but it depends on modules that are marked as OnDemand initialization. To fix this error, mark the dependency modules for InitializationMode=WhenAvailable, or remove this validation by extending the ModuleCatalog class.
```

So, my question is this: can this be done?  Obviously, the simple fix is to set both to true or both to false.  But I was hoping to avoid a little operator error with some intelligence.  I was reading the docs and it mentions a module group but I dont see how to create that in a config file.

Worst case, I suppose I could extend the class but hoping for a way to avoid that.

Comment: I wouldn't call `setting up the application` an operator job... in fact, this should be done by the installer.  If you really want to have an operator enable or disable features, create an operator-friendly settings dialog and behind that your own mechanism instead of relying on modules being loaded or not.

Comment: @Haukinger I probably should have clarified.  Yes, we should not expect end users in prod to edit this file.  The motivation here is more so the dev and qa teams can turn them on and off when the occasion comes up.  We could create some kind of user-friendlier option but sometimes its simply impossible to predict all of the scenarios.